# Eventsourced actors Replay

Tags: akka

I have been working on integrating [eventsourced](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced)  in our application for guaranteed actor message delivery.

I was looking into the message replay section - [replay-parameters](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced#replay-parameters). Our application will receive a lot of messages and we don't want the replay to start from scratch on application restart. This would dramatically increase our application start up time.

So as suggested in the wiki, we were planning to start the replay from an upper sequence number. So our application has to have some logic to define this upper sequence number.

I was wondering if there an easy way to query the eventsourced framework to find the highest sequence number of the successfully acknowledged message. In that case we need not write any logic in our app and we can start replay from this highest sequence number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is [standalone usage of reliable channels](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced#standalone-usage) (and their activation via `channel ! Deliver`). A reliable channel, when activated, automatically starts with the re-delivery of all messages that haven't been ACKed by a destination.

`ReplayParams` are for replaying messages to a processor (persistent/stateful actor). If you want to reduce recovery time of processor state, consider using [snapshots](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced#snapshots).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Seems like the standalone usage would be fit for our use case.